# Should Delete-Edited posts marked as non-constructive be reverted to its original form?

Tags: discussion

Basically I stumbled over this question asked by Cookie Monster:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/48286/delete-delete-delete-delete

Where paulmorriss, bybe and John Conde closed it as being non-constructive. True, the question at hand was non-constructive. The content of the question was later deleted by the questioner himself. Shouldn't we revert the question to its original content, so others may learn by mistake?

Are there reasons to why not to revert such questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. I just reverted it. Thanks for pointing that out.